# How the browser know which one to delete?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```js
     var b=0
    const btn = document.getElementById(`add`);
    
    btn.addEventListener(`click`, function(){
        b++;
        console.log(b)
        for (let i = b; i <= b; i++) {
            var num = i.toString();
            var yazi = document.getElementById("yazi").value;
            const li = document.createElement("li");
            li.className = `todos${num}`;
            li.innerHTML = `<div id= "yazii">${yazi}</div><div id="sil"><button class="x" id="x${num}">X</button> </div>`;
            document.getElementById("todo").appendChild(li);
            console.log(yazi);
            const sil = document.getElementById(`x${num}`);
            console.log(sil);
            sil.addEventListener(`click`, function(){
                console.log(sil);
                sil.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
            })    
    }
    });
```

```html
  <div class="container">
        <div class="todoheader">To-Do List <div id="sag"><input type="text" id="yazi"><button id="add">Add</button></div></div>
        <div class="todocontainer">
            <ul id="todo">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Im learning beginner javascript as a hobby. Tried to create a simple to-do list. It worked but after i reviewed the code, i cant understand why and how it worked. I declared "sil" as const and give it a value in every loop again and again.

1-In udemy course instrıctor pointed that const values cant be changed, so how could it worked?

2- "sil.addEventListener" -> How this listeners function deleted the correct list element?

Comment: See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const): "The const declaration creates a read-only reference to a value. It does not mean the value it holds is immutable—just that the variable identifier cannot be reassigned. `For instance, in the case where the content is an object, this means the object's contents (e.g., its properties) can be altered.`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I declared "sil" as const and give it a value in every loop again and again.

> In udemy course instrıctor pointed that const values cant be changed, so how could it worked?

Every iteration of the loop creates a new environment so every iteration basically has its own `sil` variable. You are never assigning a new value to an existing `sil` variable (which would not work as already mentioned).

> "sil.addEventListener" -> How this listeners function deleted the correct list element?

For the same reason: Every iteration has its own `sil` variable. In each iteration a new event handler is created which has access to that variable. The variable holds a reference to the element processed in that iteration of the loop.

Comment: So, if in every loop a new function is created and kept alive (please correct me if i get it wrong), the code i shared will not memory efficient way to do it?

Comment: It's not ideal, but if you have only a handful of elements, then it's not a big deal. You can also bind the same function to every element and access the element the function is bound to via `event.currentTarget` instead (you have to define the function to accept `event` as an argument).